# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](http://space.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Could the length of a craft affect it adversely during aero-breaking or gravity assist?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/could-the-length-of-a-craft-affect-it-adversely-during-aero-breaking-or-gravity)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What materials are the windows on the US Segment of the ISS made out of?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/what-materials-are-the-windows-on-the-us-segment-of-the-iss-made-out-of)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Have the micronewton thrusters developed for the LISA mission been flight tested yet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/have-the-micronewton-thrusters-developed-for-the-lisa-mission-been-flight-tested)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does the proximity of engines in engine clusters cause interference?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/does-the-proximity-of-engines-in-engine-clusters-cause-interference)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do orbital elements change when force is applied orthogonal to the velocity vector?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/how-do-orbital-elements-change-when-force-is-applied-orthogonal-to-the-velocity)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are we searching for life "as we don't know it"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/are-we-searching-for-life-as-we-dont-know-it)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Could another celestial body make a bi-elliptic transfer significantly more efficient?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3913/could-another-celestial-body-make-a-bi-elliptic-transfer-significantly-more-effi)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Do the proper ephemeri yet exist to calculate trajectories to Sedna?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/do-the-proper-ephemeri-yet-exist-to-calculate-trajectories-to-sedna)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Are the Falcon 9 landing legs aerodynamic surfaces as well?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/are-the-falcon-9-landing-legs-aerodynamic-surfaces-as-well)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What should a Discovery Program mission budget look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/what-should-a-discovery-program-mission-budget-look-like)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---